# Saving html from react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email

I have a problem with the following `exportHtml` function, this must export the html content of a react component but I can't understand why it doesn't enter the function to extrapolate html, how can I solve it?

**Editor.js**

```
import EmailEditor.js

    const Example = () => {
      const emailEditorRef = useRef(null);
      const [titolo, setTitolo] = useState('');
      const [getHtml, setHtml] = useState('');
      const [newsProfileValue, setNewsProfileSet] = useState('');
      const [profileList, setNewsProfileList] = useState([]);
      const [premiumValue, setPremium] = useState(false);
      const [publicValue, setPublic] = useState(false);
      const arr = [];
      const newsCollectionRef = collection(db, 'news');
    
      const saveDesign = () => {
        emailEditorRef.current.editor.saveDesign((design) => {
          exportData(design);
        });
      };
    
      const getList = async () => {
        try {
          var id = await localStorage.getItem('uid');
          console.log(id);
          var data = [];
          const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, 'news_profiles'));
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            if (doc.data().about.uid == id) {
              data.push({ title: doc.data().about.title, id: doc.id });
              arr.push({ doc: doc.data().about.title, id: doc.id });
            }
          });
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('Error: ' + error);
        }
        var options = arr.map((e) => {
          return `<option value="${e.id}">${e.doc}</option>`;
        });
        document.getElementById('selectNumber').innerHTML = options;
        setNewsProfileList(data);
      };
    
      const exportData = (design) => {
        const jsonString = `data:text/json;chatset=utf-8,${encodeURIComponent(
          JSON.stringify(design)
        )}`;
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = jsonString;
        link.download = 'data.json';
        link.click();
      };
      const exportHtml = () => {
        console.log('Sono in html');
        emailEditorRef.current.editor.exportHtml((data) => {
          const { design, html } = data;
          setHtml(html);
        });
        addElementToFireStoreNews(getHtml);
      
      };
    
      const addElementToFireStoreNews = async (html) => {
        try {
          console.log('Sono in addElementToFireStoreNews ');
          var uuid = await localStorage.getItem('uid');
          var jsonFile;
          var templateid = await localStorage.getItem('templateid');
          if (templateid == 1) {
            jsonFile = sample;
          } else if (templateid == 2) {
            jsonFile = sample3;
          } else {
            jsonFile = sample2;
          }
          console.log('Setup options');
          const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://link',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              Authorization: 'Bearer kjsdgu6523kjbnap!w',
            },
            data: {
              internal: true,
              online: publicValue,
              premium: premiumValue,
              html: html,
              template: jsonFile,
              subject: html,
              email: uuid,
            },
          };
          console.log('Chiamo il rest');
          axios
            .request(options)
            .then(function (response) {
              console.log('data: ' + response.data);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              console.error('Errore axios: ' + error);
            });
        } catch (err) {
          console.log('Errore inserimnento: ' + err);
        }
      };
    
      const onDesignLoad = (data) => {
        getList();
        console.log('onDesignLoad', data);
      };
    
      const onLoad = async () => {
    
    
        var templateid = await localStorage.getItem('templateid');
        if (templateid == 1) {
          emailEditorRef.current.editor.loadDesign(sample);
        } else if (templateid == 2) {
          emailEditorRef.current.editor.loadDesign(sample3);
        } else {
          emailEditorRef.current.editor.loadDesign(sample2);
        }
        emailEditorRef.current.editor.addEventListener(
          'design:loaded',
          onDesignLoad
        );
      };
    
      const onReady = () => {};
    
      const changeText = (text) => {
        setTitolo(text);
      };
    
      const clickValue = (e) => {
        setNewsProfileSet(e.target.value);
      };
    
      const changeValue = () => {
        setPremium(!premium);
      };
      const changeValuePublic = () => {
        setPublic(!publicValue);
      };
    
      return (
        <Container>
          <Bar>
            <img src="firebase.png" width="100" height="50" />
            <label style={{ color: 'white' }}>
              <b>Titolo News: </b>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="name"
                onChange={(value) => changeText(value.target.value)}
                style={{ marginRight: 200 }}
              />
              Premium:{' '}
              <Checkbox
                {...label}
                unchecked
                onClick={() => changeValue()}
                style={{ color: 'white' }}
              />
              Online:{' '}
              <Checkbox
                {...label}
                unchecked
                onClick={() => changeValuePublic()}
                style={{ color: 'white' }}
              />
            </label>
            <form id="myForm">
              <select id="selectNumber" onClick={clickValue}>
                <option>Scegli il news profile</option>
              </select>
              <button onClick={() => saveDesign}> Salva Design </button>
              <button onClick={() => exportHtml()}> Salva Articolo </button>{' '}
            </form>
          </Bar>
          <React.StrictMode>
            <EmailEditor ref={emailEditorRef} onLoad={onLoad} onReady={onReady} />{' '}
          </React.StrictMode>{' '}
        </Container>
      );
    };
    
    export default Example;
```

**EmailEditor.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { loadScript } from './loadScript';
import pkg from '../package.json';

let lastEditorId = 0;

export default class extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.editorId = props.editorId || `editor-${++lastEditorId}`;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    loadScript(this.loadEditor, this.props.scriptUrl);
  }

  render() {
    let {
      props: { minHeight = 500, style = {} },
    } = this;

    return (
      <div
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          display: 'flex',
          minHeight: minHeight,
        }}
      >
        <div id={this.editorId} style={{ ...style, flex: 1 }} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  loadEditor = () => {
    if (this.loaded) return;
    this.loaded = true;
    const options = this.props.options || {};

    if (this.props.projectId) {
      options.projectId = this.props.projectId;
    }

    if (this.props.tools) {
      options.tools = this.props.tools;
    }

    if (this.props.appearance) {
      options.appearance = this.props.appearance;
    }

    if (this.props.locale) {
      options.locale = this.props.locale;
    }

    this.editor = unlayer.createEditor({
      ...options,
      id: this.editorId,
      displayMode: 'email',
      source: {
        name: pkg.name,
        version: pkg.version,
      },
    });

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.props)) {
      if (/^on/.test(key) && key !== 'onLoad' && key !== 'onReady') {
        this.addEventListener(key, value);
      }
    }

    const { onLoad, onReady } = this.props;

    // @deprecated
    onLoad && onLoad();

    if (onReady) this.editor.addEventListener('editor:ready', onReady);
  };

  registerCallback = (type, callback) => {
    this.editor.registerCallback(type, callback);
  };

  addEventListener = (type, callback) => {
    this.editor.addEventListener(type, callback);
  };

  loadDesign = (design) => {
    this.editor.loadDesign(design);
  };

  saveDesign = (callback) => {
    this.editor.saveDesign(callback);
  };

  exportHtml = (callback) => {
    this.editor.exportHtml(callback);
  };

  setMergeTags = (mergeTags) => {
    this.editor.setMergeTags(mergeTags);
  };
}
```

Comment: from where `unlayer,createEditor` comes?

Comment: createEditor....